# Suspend function as parameter of a composable?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am new to Jetpack Compose, and I am trying to make a request trhough the function `getUserByName(string: String)` when the user clicks a button, the thing is that since I am using MVVM my request is in the ViewModel and is a suspend function. I have being doing some research and I have found that ViewModels should not be passed to composables, you pass the function instead, but when I do that I face UI issues, since the composables that I pass the function does not appear on UI. What can I be doing wrong? Here my code:

My Composable that englobes

```
@Composable
fun SearchUserScreenComposable(
    getUserByName: suspend (String) -> Unit,
    showDotaImages: Boolean
) {

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(brush = Brush.linearGradient(listOf(Blue, Tail600)))
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        )
        {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .fillMaxHeight(0.35f),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                SearchUserTextHeadLine()
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
                SearchUserTextField(getUserByName)
            }
        }
}
```

The composable where I need to do the call

```
@Composable
private fun SearchUserTextField(getUserByName: suspend (String) -> Unit) {
    var userName by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    TextField(
        trailingIcon = {
            Icon(
                Icons.Outlined.Search,
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(40.dp)
                    .padding(end = 10.dp)
                    .background(
                        if (userName.isNotEmpty()) {
                            Color.Red
                        } else {
                            Color.Transparent
                        }
                    )
                    .clickable {
                        if (userName.isNotEmpty()) {
                            scope.launch {
                                getUserByName(userName)
                            }
                        }
                    }
            )
        }
```

From where I am calling the composable that englobes

```
  setContent {
            homeScreenViewModel =
                ViewModelProvider(this, homeScreenViewModelFactory)[HomeScreenViewModel::class.java]

            var showDotaImages by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
            SearchUserScreenComposable(homeScreenViewModel::getUserByName, showDotaImages)
        }
```

Comment: If you remove the `getUserByName` parameter from both Composables, does everything display correctly?

Comment: @BenjyTec yes, I don't know what can I be doing wrong

Comment: And when you pass the `getUserByName` function to both Composables, but you never invoke it, is it displaying correctly or not? I find it just strange that this parameter would cause a Composable not to render.

Comment: You can have the data as the composable parameters. The suspend function handling can be done in the ViewModel.

Comment: Not sure why you facing the issue because of param. 
But ideally you don't need to make it suspend unless you want to wait for the completion and do something. You should make the method in viewmodel a non-suspend one and use viewModelScope to do the operation. see if it fixes the issue and also do error handling via try catch.

Comment: Place where you call composable method has two parameters, and method that you sent in definition has only one parameter. Are you sure you sent correct code, and that you call correct code?